# How do you find permutation of list in R?

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
f1= function(data){
  data1= data*2
  return (data1)
}

f2= function(data){
  data1= data*4
  return (data1)
}

f3= function(data){
  data1= data*data
  return (data1)
}

f4= function(data){
  data1= data**5
  return (data1)
}

data = matrix(1:100,10,10)
ff <- list(f1=f1,f2=f2,f3=f3,f4=f4)
```

I know how to find all possible combinations of this list using where order does not matter.

```
allcomb <- function(x) {
    do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(x), function(n) combn(x,n, simplify=FALSE)))
}
allcomb(ff)
```

However, the order matters. How would I do so? I tried doing:

```
allcomb <- function(x) {
    do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(x), function(n) permn(n)))
}
allcomb(ff)
```

The function permn only gave permutation of 4. It did not give the permutations of less than 4 which I need as well. How would I do so?

Comment: What are the contents of "f1", "f2", and so on?

Comment: f1= function(data){
  data1= data*2
  return (data1)
}

f2= function(data){
  data1= data*4
  return (data1)
}

f3= function(data){
  data1= data*data
  return (data1)
}

f4= function(data){
  data1= data**5
  return (data1)
}

data = matrix(1:100,10,10)

Comment: Please, don't post long code in the comment, update the original question.